# Which version of Taboo is the official version?

Tags: taboo

I played Taboo in college about 10 years ago and it enjoyed it thoroughly. I want to play it again. But looking at Amazon, I can't tell what game it is that I played. There's [a Hasbro version](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00D4NJSBW). There's [a Parker Brothers version](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001RN88DK). Supposedly there's even a "long out of print" [Milton Bradley version](https://ca.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130608231108AAq6pcx). And there are plenty of reviews claiming the listings are deceptive.

So which Taboo is the Taboo that I played? And if it's out of print, what's most similar to the version I played?

Comment: How are we suppose to know which version you played? Maybe you should go [here](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/1111/taboo) and look at the images of the boxes of the different versions. Year of print is also listed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to BGG, the original Taboo game was released by Hasbro in 1989.

However, the company acquired the Parker Brothers (or the remains thereof) in 1991, which can explain why there's Parker-Brother-labeled Taboo games. Later Hasbro decided to get rid of Parker Brother mentions in 2013.

So generally speaking, there has only been one version of Taboo at all times, junior and themed versions and the like excluded.

The main differences over the year are

- of course up-to-date cards (asking for current events gets a bit weird, when the game you're playing is ten years old)
- a playing board used to track progress
- different versions of sound device used to signal an error (some honk-like thing vs a classic buzzer)

There's a version called XXL with additional challenges besides the "classic" taboo cards, like drawing, some kind of puppet-charade and community-rounds.